# Having issue with Having Query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do this query:

```
SELECT *, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(43.656906) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-79.434356) ) + sin( radians(43.656906) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM Locations HAVING distance < 10 AND HAVING category='%Family%'
```

But I get this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'HAVING category='%Family%' LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Does anybody know what is the problem?

Comment: Remove second `having` filter

Comment: I need it to have it for my result lol...

Comment: I mean remove `having` only rest should stay like `AND  category='%Family%'`

Comment: But it return 0 rows when I remove having...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope category is column in your table

```
   SELECT *, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(43.656906) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-79.434356) ) + sin( radians(43.656906) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM Locations where  category like '%Family%' HAVING distance < 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the second `HAVING` and just use `AND` to tell MySQL that both conditions must hold.

```
SELECT *, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(43.656906) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-79.434356) ) + sin( radians(43.656906) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM Locations HAVING distance < 10 AND category='%Family%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not add having conditions twice .You can use "AND" inside the "Having" condition.So the code will be :

```
SELECT *, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(43.656906) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-79.434356) ) + sin( radians(43.656906) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM Locations HAVING distance < 10 AND category='%Family%'
```